# R - Skip columns in pmax command if they do not exist

Tags: r

I'd like to use the pmax command to create a new column. My code Looks like this:

```
Master <- Master %>%
  mutate(RAM = pmax(RAM1, RAM2, RAM3, RAM4, RAM5, RAM6, RAM7, RAM8, RAM9,   RAM10,
                    RAM11,  RAM12,  RAM13,  RAM14,  RAM15,  RAM16,  RAM17,  RAM18,
                    RAM19,  RAM20,  RAM21,  RAM22,  RAM23,  RAM24,  RAM25,  RAM26,
                    RAM27,  RAM28,  RAM29,  RAM30,  RAM31,  RAM32,  RAM33,  RAM34,
                    RAM35,  RAM36,  RAM37,  RAM38,  RAM39,  RAM40,  RAM41,  RAM42,
                    RAM43,  RAM44,  RAM45,  RAM46,  RAM47,  RAM48,  RAM49,  RAM50,
                    RAM51,  RAM52,  RAM53,  RAM54,  RAM55,  RAM56,  RAM57,  RAM58,
                    RAM59,  RAM60,  RAM61,  RAM62,  RAM63,  RAM64,  RAM65,  RAM66,
                    RAM67,  RAM68,  RAM69,  RAM70,  RAM71,  RAM72,  RAM73,  RAM74,
                    RAM75,  RAM76,  RAM77,  RAM78,  RAM79,  RAM80,  RAM81,  RAM82,
                    RAM83,  RAM84,  RAM85,  RAM86,  RAM87,  RAM88,  RAM89,  RAM90,
                    RAM91,  RAM92, na.rm =T))
```

In my current data base, however, only the columns RAM1 to RAM8 exist. In this case, I want R to skip all the other columns mentioned in the Statement and to only use column RAM1 to RAM8 (it is okay if R displays an error message, but I don't want the program to interrupt running the code).

Any ideas how to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be as follows:

Set up some data to make a reproducible example

```
set.seed(0)
Master <- data.frame(Other=100,RAM1=1:10, RAM2=1:10, RAM3=1:10, RAM4=1:10, 
                     RAM5=1:10, RAM6=1:10, RAM7=1:10, RAM8=rnorm(10)+5)
Master[5,5] <- NA
```

Select required columns of the dataframe:

```
Master[colnames(Master) %in% paste0("RAM",1:92)]
```

Use do.call to run pmax using the selected columns as arguments, and adding the argument `na.rm=TRUE`

```
Master$RAM <- do.call(pmax, c(Master[colnames(Master) %in% paste0("RAM",1:92)], na.rm=TRUE))
```

Sample output:

```
Master
#   Other RAM1 RAM2 RAM3 RAM4 RAM5 RAM6 RAM7     RAM8       RAM
#1    100    1    1    1    1    1    1    1 6.262954  6.262954
#2    100    2    2    2    2    2    2    2 4.673767  4.673767
#3    100    3    3    3    3    3    3    3 6.329799  6.329799
#4    100    4    4    4    4    4    4    4 6.272429  6.272429
#5    100    5    5    5   NA    5    5    5 5.414641  5.414641
#6    100    6    6    6    6    6    6    6 3.460050  6.000000
#7    100    7    7    7    7    7    7    7 4.071433  7.000000
#8    100    8    8    8    8    8    8    8 4.705280  8.000000
#9    100    9    9    9    9    9    9    9 4.994233  9.000000
#10   100   10   10   10   10   10   10   10 7.404653 10.000000
```

Comment: Thank you a thousand times, this works perfectly! Do you know if there is also a way to run your code for more than one variable at a time? For example, if I have a variable called "BDF" for which I have the same Problem as for RAM?